# If I create an android emulator device in visual studio, what is it doing to my c drive?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-emulator, partition

very noob question here. I am trying to start building an android app using visual studio xamarin and right now I just want to test a simple hello world app to make sure everything is working. However, to debug my code, I must create a new android emulator device and it is asking me what the "disk.dataPartition.size" value should be. I checked the "skin.path" and it says it is "C:\Program Files (x86)]Mi..." So does this mean it is going to partition my c drive? I really can't be partitioning my c drive and I don't want to mess up my computer by doing this.

Comment: No, it's just asking for how much disk space it will allocate for your emulator. It won't mess anything in your computer.

Comment: Look up "[virtual disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_disk_and_virtual_drive)" :)